# Ajax sending a get to orignal page rather than a post to a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that when I submit it I want to load the result page into a div on the original page. When I click the submit button of the form however it is sending a get requst to the original page eg: http://localhost/hr/index_admin_test.php?posteddate=01-10-2015 rather than a post request to http://localhost/hr/attendanceform2.php

In the original page I have the following script:

```
 <script>
 $('#timesheetsearch form').submit(function(){
      var data=$(this).serialize();
      // post data
      $.post('attendanceform2.php', data , function(returnData){
                  $('#timesheets').html( returnData)
      })

      return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
});
  </script>
```

And in the body of the page I have the following form and div:

```
    <div class="content_text" id="timesheetsearch">
            <p> Select the date you wish to view time sheets for:</p>

            <p><form name="timesheetsearch"> <br><input name="posteddate"  value="01-10-2015" id="datepicker" />
            <div id="timesheets"></div>
 <input type="submit"> </form> </p>
```

Comment: Have you tried a forward slash? i.e.   $.post('/attendanceform2.php',... It may make a difference

Comment: Thanks - doesn't seem to make a difference though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the script after the form like this

```
    <div class="content_text" id="timesheetsearch">
                <p> Select the date you wish to view time sheets for:</p>

                <p><form name="timesheetsearch"> <br><input name="posteddate"  value="01-10-2015" id="datepicker" />
                <div id="timesheets"></div>
     <input type="submit"> </form> </p>

     <script>
     $('#timesheetsearch form').submit(function(){
          var data=$(this).serialize();
          // post data
          $.post('attendanceform2.php', data , function(returnData){
                      $('#timesheets').html( returnData)
          })

          return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
    });
      </script>
```

If you run your script before loading the form it will not work since script didn't find any form. You can also write your script inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

If you really want your script to place before the form. Hope your script is working correctly now.

Comment: Thank you it has solved the problem and is actually far easier for me to follow what is going on in the pages.

Comment: @LauraMorris I will recommend you to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post`. `$.ajax` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

1st you can try

```
<form method="post" action="attendanceform2.php" name="timesheetsearch">
```

2nd try

```
$(document).on('submit','#timesheetsearch form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

3rd  check your attendanceform2.php file path

4th use it with 1st

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#timesheetsearch form').submit(function(){
    //or you can use this instead>> $(document).on('submit','#timesheetsearch form',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data=$(this).serialize();
      // post data
      $.post('attendanceform2.php', data , function(returnData){
                  $('#timesheets').html( returnData);
      });

      return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
 });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: The 1st edit makes my form submit to the correct file but it goes to that page rather than loading it into the timesheets div on the original page.

Comment: When I put in the 2nd edit as well nothing happens when I click submit. I'm relatively new to javascript - what is the e in the function() ?

Comment: try to use 1st and e.preventDefault(); together ..2nd should work .. check your console for errors.... last thing wrap your code inside $(document).ready(); .. i will update my answer and about (e)  https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/